# How to create a code to insert an integer into a linked list in a sorted manner?

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

It is a part of my assignment. I have to place a number into the linked list. It has to be in order, and it cannot allow duplicates.

I tried the following code, but I always end up in segmentation faults.

```
int insertSortedLL(LinkedList *ll, int item)
{
    ListNode *current;
    int index=0;
    int res;

    if (ll == NULL || ll->head->item >= item) 
    {
        res=insertNode(ll,0,item);
        return 0;
    } 
    else
    { 
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        current = ll->head; 
        while (current->next!=NULL)
        { 
            if(current->next->item==item){
                return -1;
            }
            else if(current->next->item < item){
                current = current->next;
                index++;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        } 
        res=insertNode(ll,index,item);
        return index;
    } 
}
```

I expected it to return a value, which is an index of the number it is stored, but it never worked. Also, `int insertNode` is a pre-made function to insert a number in a chosen index, and `ListNode` is to define the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that are wrong in your code.

1. Even if the linked list passed as argument is NULL you still call `insertNode(ll,0,item)`. If the linked list is NULL, this will cause a segmentation fault 100% of the time.

```
    if (ll == NULL || ll->head->item >= item) 
    {
        res=insertNode(ll,0,item);
        return 0;
    }
```

2. The logic is a bit odd. Is seems that you don't want items to be repeated in your list as i deduce from this if statement (`if(current->next->item==item)`) but you don't check this condition for the first item of the list.
3. Using the function `insertNode` makes your code less eficient. insertNode will need to loop through the list again to put the new item in the right place.

EDIT: This is a dirty fix (compared to the other version) in order to not allow duplicates in the list.

```
ListNode* make_node(int item){
    ListNode * new = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    new->item = item;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}

int insertSortedLL(LinkedList *ll, int item){
    ListNode *current;
    ListNode *new;
    ListNode *tmp;
    int index=0;

    if(ll == NULL)
        return -1;

    //If the list is empty
    if(ll->head == NULL){
        ll->head = make_node(item);
    }

    if(ll->head->item == item)
        return -1;

    if(ll->head->item > item){
        new = make_node(item);
        new->next = ll->head;
        ll->head = new;
        return 0;
    }

    /* General case */
    current = ll->head; 
    while (current != NULL){
        if(current->next == NULL){
            current->next = make_node(item);
            return index;
        }else if (current->next->item == item){
            return -1;
        }else if (current->next->item < item){
            current = current->next;
            index++;
        }else{
            new = make_node(item);
            tmp = current->next;
            new->next = tmp;
            current->next = new;
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Edit: This is the version that allows duplicates.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int insertSortedLL(LinkedList *ll, int item){
    ListNode *current;
    ListNode *new;
    ListNode *tmp;
    int index=0;

    if(ll == NULL)
        return -1;

    new = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    new->item = item;
    new->next = NULL;

    //If the list is empty or the first item of ll is greater
    if(ll->head == NULL || ll->head->item >= item){
        new->next = ll->head;
        ll->head = new;
        return 0;
    }

    /* General case */
    current = ll->head; 
    while (current != NULL){
        if(current->next == NULL){
            current->next = new;
            return index;
        }else if (current->next->item < item){
            current = current->next;
            index++;
        }else{
            tmp = current->next;
            new->next = tmp;
            current->next = new;
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

A usefull tool for finding which piece of code generates the Segmentation Fault message is `valgrind` (and does a lot more things like finding memory leaks, etc).

Compile your code using `-g -Wall -Wextra`, don't ignore compiler warning messages (even if they seem harmless), and run the program with `valgrind`.

Comment: Yes, I didn't check that condition because i wasn't sure if you really wanted that or not. I just added a version that doesn't allow duplicates. Next time you post a question give us more details about what you want to do (lists with duplicates are completly normal).